# emacs gdb how to keep only one history

Tags: gdb, history

As in title, When I do use gdb mode with Emacs the history run with the command `M-r` and `C-c C-x` seems to be different, depending on which frame the gdb was started in the first place!
How do I make one unique history for all the frames, all the windows, for entire Emacs ?